# JavaFx text movement animation

Tags: java, animation, javafx

Hi I want to do something like this:
I have text and I want the text to be moving from right to left all the time. I want to set bounds to moving text is a pane bounds. Now I have this but it doesn't work the way I want it to work

```
  public static void start(Text msg) {
    msg.setTextOrigin(VPos.TOP);
    double sceneWidth = Config.xSize;
    double msgWidth = msg.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
    KeyValue initKeyValue = new KeyValue(msg.translateXProperty(), sceneWidth);
    KeyFrame initFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, initKeyValue);
    KeyValue endKeyValue = new KeyValue(msg.translateXProperty(), -1.0
        * msgWidth);
    KeyFrame endFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(50), endKeyValue);
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(initFrame, endFrame);
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
```

I want to in my application have a slide text on right to left

Comment: What exactly do you mean by it is not working the way you want it to be? Is it being animated just once? Or nothing happens? Or is it going upside down? What is happening? Our ability to help is limited to how much you help us understand the problem.

Comment: @iMan I edit my post

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `KeyValue endKeyValue` and `KeyFrame endFrame` **-->** remove them.  Add `timeline.setAutoReverse(true);` before `timeline.play();`.

`Timeline timeline = new Timeline(initFrame, endFrame);` **-->** `Timeline timeline = new Timeline(initFrame);`

Hope i could help you with that.

**Edit:**

Change the `initFrame`'s duration to `Duration.seconds(50)` or something else.